# Passing String variable as an index to Integer variable in c

Tags: c

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    char s[]={"this is string"};
    while(s[i]!=0)
    {
        printf("%c",i[s]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This Program does not give error and produce output as "this is string". 
why..??

Comment: `s[i]` and `i[s]` are same as `*(s + i)`.

Comment: Short answer: don't write weird crap like that and you don't have to worry about why it works. Knowing that you can change the place of the `s` and `i` is useless knowledge.

Comment: Please format your code (like in your C textbook).